# Extract DNS record (MX) details from name server reply c++

Tags: c++, dns, mail-server, nslookup

I am trying to get the hostname of the MX record with low priority using the following code, but I am unable to parse the required details (hostname, ttl, priority) from the given nameserver reply.

```
u_char nsbuf[4096], dispbuf[4096];
ns_msg msg;
ns_rr rr;
int i, j, l;
std::string domain("gmail.com");
l = res_query(domain.c_str(), ns_c_any, ns_t_mx, nsbuf, sizeof (nsbuf));

    ns_initparse(nsbuf, l, &msg);
    printf("%s :\n", domain.c_str());
    l = ns_msg_count(msg, ns_s_an);
    for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
    {
        int prr = ns_parserr(&msg, ns_s_an, j, &rr);


        ns_sprintrr(&msg, &rr, NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<char*> (dispbuf), sizeof (dispbuf));

        printf("%s\n", dispbuf);
    }
```

The above code gives the result as

> gmail.com.              15M IN MX       30
>   alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Is there any available function to get hostname, priority, ttl, etc. in separate buffers like below?

> host -> alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
>
> priority -> 30
>
> ttl -> 15M

And, should we manually check for the higher priority record,
or is there any utility function or code that could do the requirement?

**Edit:**

I tried the following code to extract data

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    u_char nsbuf[4096];
    u_char dispbuf[4096];
    ns_msg msg;
    ns_rr rr;
    int i, j, l;
    std::string domain("gmail.com");
    l = res_query(domain.c_str(), ns_c_any, ns_t_mx, nsbuf, sizeof (nsbuf));
    if (l < 0) {
        perror(domain.c_str());
    } else {
#ifdef USE_PQUERY
        res_pquery(&_res, nsbuf, l, stdout);
#else
        ns_initparse(nsbuf, l, &msg);
        l = ns_msg_count(msg, ns_s_an);
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            int prr = ns_parserr(&msg, ns_s_an, j, &rr);

            //BLOCK 1
            char *cp;
            cp = (char *) ns_rr_name(rr);
            printf("CP->%s\n", (char *) cp);
            int i1 = ns_rr_type(rr);
            printf("Type->%d\n", i1);
            int i2 = ns_rr_class(rr);
            printf("Class->%d\n", i2);
            int i3 = ns_rr_ttl(rr);
            printf("TTL->%d\n", i3);
            int i4 = ns_rr_rdlen(rr);
            printf("DataLength->%d\n", i4);

            //BLOCK 2
            const u_char *rdata = ns_rr_rdata(rr) +1;
            printf("DataU_char-> %s\n", reinterpret_cast<const char*> (rdata));

            int len = strlen(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (rdata));
            printf("len->%d\n", len);

            char rdatatemp[1024];
            strncpy(rdatatemp, reinterpret_cast<const char*> (rdata), sizeof (rdatatemp));
            printf("DataChar->%s\n", rdatatemp);

            ns_sprintrr(&msg, &rr, NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<char*> (dispbuf), sizeof (dispbuf));
            printf("FullRecord->%s\n", dispbuf);
            printf("\n");
        }
#endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works well for txt record, but for mx record, it is not parsed correctly and the following is the result

**Output:**

CP->gmail.com
Type->15
Class->1
TTL->130
DataLength->32
DataU_char-> gmail-smtp-inlgoogle��
len->33
DataChar->gmail-smtp-inlgoogle��
FullRecord->gmail.com.          2m10s IN MX     30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

CP->gmail.com
Type->15
Class->1
TTL->130
DataLength->9
DataU_char-> alt2�.�
len->10
DataChar->alt2�.�
FullRecord->gmail.com.          2m10s IN MX     20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

So in DataChar & DataU_char special symbols are printed. 
'alt2�.�' is printed instead of 'alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.'
Also the DataLength value is wrong.
Also I am not able to get the priority of the record.
Am I missing something here, or is it the error with the c++ library itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libresolv` doesn't have public functions to unpack specific resource record types, but there *are* functions inside it to help you do it yourself.

In particular, look at `dn_expand` which can read a (compressed) domain name and `ns_get16` which will read a big-endian two-octet field from a record, so in your case:

```
char exchange[NS_MAXDNAME];

const u_char *rdata = ns_rr_rdata(rr);

const uint16_t pri = ns_get16(rdata);
int len = dn_expand(nsbuf, nsbuf + msg_len, rdata + 2, exchange, sizeof(exchange));

printf("Pri->%d\n", pri);
printf("Exchange->%s\n", exchange);
```

where `msg_len` replaces your overwritten `l` variable, containing the length of the received packet.

The `rdata + 2` in the call to `dn_expand()` skips the 16 bit priority field.

Comment: I just tried what was in the answer and got priority right, but exchange was empty. The variable len was -1 and i could not figure out what is msg_len.

Comment: @fury.slay in your original code you assign `l = res_query(...)` but then you overwrite that variable with the result of `ns_msg_count()`.  You need to store that original value of `l` in `msg_len`

Comment: should we manually check which has least priority and use that record, or is there any api for it?

Comment: there's no API in libresolv to pick which MX record should be used.  Also, don't forget that in the absence of any MX record, an `A` or `AAAA` record should be treated as an MX with priority 0.