# c++ sockets - smtp server hostname from email address

Tags: c++, sockets, email

Is there a generic solution to lookup smtp server hostname or ip from an email address in c/c++?

Up to now I am just preceding the domain name by "smtp.", but I am not sure if this is guaranteed in general?

One last thing, I am still using getaddrinfo to get to the actual IP. Is it still standard ? At least I have the feeling it should be outdated by now :D.

Comment: Email address and the address of the e-mail server are not related at all. They don't even map 1-to-1. That is the same e-mail address can be handled by different servers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a bit confused now. So email address example@gmail.com and server name smtp.gmail.com are not related ? Further how can email addresses be handled by different servers ? I mean if i want to send a mail from example@gmail.com, i have to provide username/password, so I dont understand how diffrent server but gmail.com can handle email address (username/password). Can you give me some reference providing some more informations about your comment ?

Comment: @OZ17 when you send an email, you first connect and login to **your email provider's** SMTP server (eg, Gmail), and then send the email to that server. If the recipient is on the same system, the email is delivered directly to that user's inbox. Otherwise, if the recipient is on another system, the email has to be relayed. Your provider uses DNS to query the SMTP server(s) for the recipient's domain, then forwards the email to each of those servers until one of them is successful.

Comment: @OZ17 `gmail.com` as a service handles the `example@gmail.com` account, but employs multiple SMTP servers around the world, so there is no 1-to-1 relationship between the `gmail.com` domain and a specific SMTP server. When that user sends emails, (s)he has to login to one of those servers for authentication. When other people send emails to `example@gmail.com`, those emails may pass through different/multiple SMTP servers as they get routed around the Internet to reach the final inbox. If you look at an email's raw headers, you will see a list of SMTP servers that the email has passed through.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for explaining me what VTT has written. I totally misinterpreted his comment XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a generic solution to lookup smtp server hostname or ip from an email address in c/c++?

Not a generic solution, no. Though there are surely 3rd party SMTP libraries available with that capability, if you look around.

> Up to now I am just preceding the domain name by "smtp.", but I am not sure if this is guaranteed in general?

No, it is not. The *proper* solution is to extract the domain portion of the email address (everything after the `@`), and then perform a DNS lookup asking for the MX records of that domain.  Those records will provide the hostname(s) of the domain's SMTP server(s), and the priority order in which they should be used. You can then resolve those hostnames to IP addresses using additional DNS lookups asking for A (IPv4) and AAAA (IPv6) records as needed.

However, if your goal is to send emails *directly* to a given domain's SMTP system, DON'T.  The *correct* solution is to send the emails via your own email provider's SMTP server instead, and let it relay emails to other SMTP systems as needed.  As an anti-spam measure, most SMTP servers do not allow email deliveries from unknown sources, only from their own users, and from other known and trusted ISP/SMTP systems that have been whitelisted for relaying purposes.

> One last thing, I am still using getaddrinfo to get to the actual IP. Is it still standard ?

For the purpose of resolving a hostname to an IP address, yes.

But you cannot use `getaddrinfo()` to retrieve a domain's SMTP hostnames.  You have to directly query a DNS server for that (there are plenty of DNS libraries available, or you can implement the DNS protocol manually in your own code).

Comment: You saved my day !!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688432/querying-mx-record-in-c-linux has the implementation! Best Regards