# mail submission agent (MSA) server hostname from email address via c++

Tags: sockets, email, resolve, smtps

I am looking for a generic way to get the hostname of mail submission servers by only having the email address with c/c++, so I can connect to port 587 and/or 465 smtp submission.

E.g. example@gmail.com -> smtp.gmail.com or gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com

Basically I am sending some specific emails on behalf of clients. So at the end it looks like they have sent the email. Up to now I am still using a simple domain to hostname map like {gmail.com,smtp.gmail.com} which I extend whenever needed. However I would very much like to avoid this map and automate this process.

A while ago I posted [c++ sockets - smtp server hostname from email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417266/c-sockets-smtp-server-hostname-from-email-address), which should have been the same question, maybe it was not clear enough. In the answer I was advised to perform DNS lookup and ask for MX records. A book and an implementation later I noticed that these mx records are not suitable for mail submission (can't connect to port 587, only 25). I checked all other types defined in resolv.h and checked nslookup (which is probably using resolv.h anyway) and by now I really think this is not doable via DNS lookup. If somebody wants to try it, check `nslookup -type=mx gmail.com` you will not see any -msa... stuff.

I am a bit desperate now, because I really want to get it done. However I also dont want to spend weeks on it. I would be also really happy about an answer telling me that it is not doable in a reasonable amount of time.

---

EDIT:

Following a minimal example I just made very quick via the DNS MX approach and where i tried to connect to ports 25, 465, 587.

```
/*c++1z, Don't forget -lresolv*/
#include <resolv.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

//like assert but throws instead
#define CHECK(condition)\
    if(!(condition)){\
        std::ostringstream oss;\
        oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "\nerrno:" << errno << "\nh_errno:" << h_errno << std::endl;\
        throw std::runtime_error(oss.str());\
    }

//!
//! \brief mxRecords performs dns T_MX lookup
//! \param domain the domain part of the email e.g. example@gmail.com -> gmail.com
//! \return multimap of {priority, server hostname} pairs
//!
auto mxRecords(std::string const&domain)
->std::multimap<size_t/*priority*/,std::string/*server name*/>
{
    std::basic_string<unsigned char> response(PACKETSZ,'0');
    int response_size = res_search(domain.data(),C_IN,T_MX,response.data(),response.size());
    CHECK(response_size != -1);
    response.resize(response_size);

    ns_msg handle;
    CHECK(ns_initparse(response.data(),response.size(),&handle) != -1);

    std::multimap<size_t,std::string> ret;
    for(int i = 0; i < ns_msg_count(handle,ns_s_an); ++i)
    {
        ns_rr rr;
        if(ns_parserr(&handle,ns_s_an,i,&rr) == -1)
            continue;
        if(ns_rr_type(rr) != ns_t_mx)
            continue;
        std::string exp_dn(MAXDNAME,0);
        if(ns_name_uncompress(ns_msg_base(handle),ns_msg_end(handle),ns_rr_rdata(rr)+NS_INT16SZ,exp_dn.data(),exp_dn.size()) == -1)
            continue;
        ret.emplace(ns_get16(ns_rr_rdata(rr)),exp_dn.data());
    }
    return ret;
}
bool __connect(std::string const&host, std::string const&port)
{
    addrinfo const __req{0,AF_UNSPEC,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP,0,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr};
    addrinfo *__pai(nullptr);
    if(getaddrinfo(host.data(),port.data(),&__req,&__pai) != 0)
        return false;
    for(addrinfo *iter = __pai; iter != nullptr; iter = iter->ai_next)
    {
        int fd = socket(iter->ai_family, iter->ai_socktype, iter->ai_protocol);
        if(fd == -1)
            continue;
        int retries = 1;
        setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_SYNCNT, &retries, sizeof(retries));
        if(::connect(fd, iter->ai_addr, iter->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            close(fd);
            continue;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(__pai);
        close(fd);
        return true;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(__pai);
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    std::string domain = "gmail.com";

    //get mx records and try to connect for port 25,465,587
    auto mx_records = mxRecords(domain);
    std::cout << "----------MX RECORDS <priority|host|port25|port465|port587> for " << domain << std::endl;
    for(auto iter = mx_records.begin(); iter != mx_records.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << " | " << iter->second;
        //try port 25|port 465 | port 587
        for(auto port : {"25","465","587"})
        {
            if(__connect(iter->second,port))
                std::cout << " | y";
            else
                std::cout << " | n";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives as output

```
----------MX RECORDS <priority|host|port25|port465|port587> for gmail.com
5 | gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com | y | n | n
10 | alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com | y | n | n
20 | alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com | y | n | n
30 | alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com | y | n | n
40 | alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com | y | n | n
```

Please note the *"in"* inside these hostnames. I made a dns query for cname of *smtp.gmail.com* and it gives me *gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com* so *"msa"*, which is open for ports 587/465. I really think these mx records are nowadays only good for port 25 and not for mail submission.

---

EDIT #2:

There is a lot of confusion about ports 25, 465, 587 on internet. Just to clear things up for me these ports don't differ in ssl/tls a priory. Port 25 is e.g. when you want to send a email from example@yourDomain.com to example@gmail.com. Port 587 is e.g. when you want to send a email from example1@gmail.com to example2@gmail.com. Finally port 465[deprecated] is just the same as 587 with the addition that it starts already with ssl/tls. Please correct me if I am wrong, but I am pretty sure I am not! Following the logs of 3 EHLO runs from my real application. First using a mx record hostname and port 25, second using "smtp.gmail.com" and port 587 and last one using "smtp.gmail.com" and port 465. Notice the difference for 587/465 having an AUTH command option after secure connection and 25 having no AUTH option. So when sending emails over port 25 reciever gets informed that sender is not verified and you usually get blocked (SPAM) soon. Anyway I need this AUTH command, application is totally legal no spamming etc. and this is the reason why I need smtp servers which have port 587 open and I dont think these MX servers are the correct ones.

PORT-25

```
S:220 mx.google.com ESMTP ############### - gsmtp
C:EHLO ###############
S:250-mx.google.com at your service, ###############
  250-SIZE 157286400
  250-8BITMIME
  250-STARTTLS
  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  250-PIPELINING
  250-CHUNKING
  250 SMTPUTF8
C:STARTTLS
S:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C:EHLO ###############
S:250-mx.google.com at your service, ###############
  250-SIZE 157286400
  250-8BITMIME
  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  250-PIPELINING
  250-CHUNKING
  250 SMTPUTF8
C:QUIT
S:221 2.0.0 closing connection ############### - gsmtp
```

PORT-587

```
S:220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ############### - gsmtp
C:EHLO ###############
S:250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, ###############
  250-SIZE 35882577
  250-8BITMIME
  250-STARTTLS
  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  250-PIPELINING
  250-CHUNKING
  250 SMTPUTF8
C:STARTTLS
S:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
C:EHLO ###############
S:250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, ###############
  250-SIZE 35882577
  250-8BITMIME
  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  250-PIPELINING
  250-CHUNKING
  250 SMTPUTF8
C:QUIT
S:221 2.0.0 closing connection ############### - gsmtp
```

PORT-465

```
S:220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ############### - gsmtp
C:EHLO ###############
S:250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, ###############
  250-SIZE 35882577
  250-8BITMIME
  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
  250-PIPELINING
  250-CHUNKING
  250 SMTPUTF8
C:QUIT
S:221 2.0.0 closing connection ############### - gsmtp
```

Comment: That answer was given to you by me, and what I said before still applies to this same issue. Yes, you perform a DNS lookup for the email domain's MX records.  That is how you discover the SMTP server's address(es), which you can then connect to normally using TCP.  The port is not handled by DNS, which is why you don't see it in the DNS data.  YOU decide which port to connect to, depending on whether you need to communicate with the SMTP server over implicit SSL (port 465), explicit TLS (port 25 or 587, using the `STARTTLS` command), or not (port 25).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you again for trying to help me! I included an example in the answer which is following your advice from last answer. I think these servers listed in the mx records are not open for other ports but 25.

Comment: I've removed the 'c++' label, it does not seem to be relevant. I do not know why this was downvoted. To me, it looks a perfectly valid technical question, and I upvoted it, so you are back at 0 :). Also, **downvotes should be customarily given a reason**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the OP is acting *on behalf of the client*, so pretending to be an MUA is warranted in this case. Your answer is correct, but it's an answer to a different question. In the SaaS world, everything is backwards and upside down! :) And I, being with a SaaS provider company myself, certainly sympathize; clients are known to change their network configuration not thinking twice about notifying their partners.

Comment: @kkm Question was downvoted more than once. Maybe because of my english :D.

Comment: I did not downvote, because the form of the question looks correct to me - and anyway I'm not a native English speaker either. But sending a mail *on behalf* of your users with their own credentials and to their mail submission server looks like a poor solution on a security point of view. Passwords are to be kept secret.

Comment: @SergeBallesta *looks like a poor solution* solution for which problems? I never posted any specific problems the application is solving... Anyway the question itself has already a perfect answer!

Comment: @OZ17: I did not want to be offensive. I just wanted to warn future readers that knowing passwords for third party persons is not conformant with best security practices.  You know whether it may be a problem or not for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not technically required to be supported, but per [RFC 6186 Sec. 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186#section-3.1) you should query for SRV records for the `_submission` host in the `_tcp` subdomain, like so:

```
$ nslookup -type=srv _submission._tcp.gmail.com
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
_submission._tcp.gmail.com      SRV service location:
          priority       = 5
          weight         = 0
          port           = 587
          svr hostname   = smtp.gmail.com
```

Some things you should keep in mind:

1. This is a "convenience feature", in a sense. If you have an e-mail address `myname@acme.com`, then acme.com may (or may not) expose these RFC 6186 records in `_tcp.acme.com` to allow their users' mail client program to automatically discover services such as POP3, IMAP etc.
2. There may be special restrictions imposed on connecting to a domain MSA. For example, the services may simply refuse connections from machines outside of `xyz.com` internal network, or require an internally trusted certificate, and so on. The MSA is intended for interacting with the mail client, MUA, not for general mail delivery.

Comment: Great Thank you! I have just tried it for gmx `nslookup -type=srv _submission._tcp.gmx.com` and it already did not work. So does it mean that they already dont support it ?

Comment: Generally, you may query for `type=ns` to get the authoritative DNS server first and query it, but in your case, the authoritative answer is same: `nslookup -type=ns _submission._tcp.gmx.com ns-gmx.ui-dns.com` reports no answer.

Comment: So as far as I can see this right now this is the correct answer, but it is not even worth for me to make a c++ implementation when it is already not working for gmx right ? Would you agree ?

Comment: Depends on your numbers. If you have a 1000 clients, and 500 of them expose the config in their DNS, then this takes away half of your headache. Since in the real world the config would not be correct for another 250 of the 500 who do, downgrade that to a quarter. We have a lot of customer interaction (SIP trunks, all sorts of Web APIs and other ways of data exchange), and they accidentally break them every day by what they think are innocuous changes. But as I said, this is not a requirement, and provided for conveniently auto-configuring email clients. In the end, you've got what you've got.

Comment: Great thank you very much! Would you maybe allow me to add a c++ routine to this answer later on when I implement it and maybe just check if it looks good?

Comment: I do not think, frankly, that this would improve the answer. Your question is pretty general, and not tied to any particular language; if your routine was written in e. g. Python, the answer would still be same. If you have a specific question about using the sockets API in C++, it is better, IMO, to post a separate question if you are stuck. Think of it: “Why cannot I get a response from gethostaddr()” is an API usage question, not related to *why* you are querying the DNS.

Comment: You are right. I have finished it anyway by now, works fine. I was just thinking that If I would have seen an implementation 2 weeks ago, I would have spend maybe 5 min on it and not numerous hours reading DNS & BIND ~600 pages and many more ... Still for those who are interested just adjust the code in the question for 3x16 bits integers, one domain and ofc use srv type. Thank you @kkm for everything!!!